# Minimum value of the following expressions

Tags: trigonometry

1) What's the minimum for the function $E(x)= \sqrt3\cos x+ \sin x$) for all real x?. I tried taking the derivative of $\sin(x+ \frac{\pi}{3})$ and  $\cos(x+ \frac{\pi}{3})$ but I don't know how to resolve it from here.

2) What is the minimum of $OM+MC$ knowing that $xm+ym=6$, and the point O is at (0,0), and the point C is at (0,4)?

Comment: You seem like a relatively new user to me, and here are some tips to help people understand your question better. 1) Please improve your MathJax formatting, and put extra brackets to improve readability. 2) Keep your questions relevant so that they stay on the same topic.

Comment: This is the link to the MathJax formatting page: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, $$E(x) = 2\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x\right) = 2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\geq-2$$
because $\sin x\geq -1$ for all $x$.

For the second problem, you find the answer by looking for the symmetry point of $O$ with regards to the line $x+y=6$, which is $O'=(6,6)$, and then finding the intersection of $O'C:y=\frac{1}{3}x+4$ with $x+y=6$, which is the point $M:\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much,I forgot the 2 when I divided the expression so it gave me -1 which wasn't the answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped! :)